# Does Harbor Master really want 100+ Product containers?

Tags: mafia-wars-2

The Harbor Master has given me a quest to give him 10 Product containers. However, after buying them, I have returned to him and given him 10 containers. After that, progress bar just jumped to the 10% mark and he wanted more…

Does he really want me to spend around 10,000 products to buy ~100 product containers?

Comment: I haven't completed any of the Wharf quests yet, but thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this blog](http://mafia-warszynga.blogspot.com/2011/11/cannot-complete-give-harbor-master-some.html), the Zynga support team is aware of this bug.

> Some players cannot complete the Westside Wharf mission "Give the Harbor Master some Product Containers".
>   When they collect all ten of the product containers, and give them to the Harbor Master, the mission only shows partial credit.
>
> We will work to get this mission fixed as soon as possible.
>
> Thanks for your patience!
>
> --The Mafia Wars 2 Support Team